# How to localize the QFileDialog called from QPrintDialog?

Tags: qt, localization, qt4, qfiledialog

The following works fine for localizing the QPrintDialog:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QPrintDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    if (translator.load("./translations/qt_de.qm")) {
       a.installTranslator(&translator);
    }

    QPrintDialog printdialog;
    printdialog.exec();
}
```

But when I click on the "Choose file"-Button (with the three dots) in the QPrintDialog, the english version of the file dialog comes up instead of the german one I'd like to have.

Also, there is a warning at the console:

> KGlobal::locale::Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work

Where should I look?

As for the workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110254/1219282): Some QDialogs support a ::DontUseNativeDialog flag, but the QPrintDialog doesn't.

(tested on linux, don't know how the outcome is on other platforms)

Answer (score 0):

try to add after translator.load this line:

a::installTranslator(&translator);//or something like that(*)

and read docs about QApplication::installTranslator methods...

(*) sorry I checked and it's a QCoreApplication's method. I used it into a QMainWindow subclass by qApp macro, i don't know how to call that from main.cpp. Please do some test.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself having the same problem and I worked around it by adding to my main window:
`QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontUseNativeDialogs);`

You can find the enum with the attributes [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum).